# why exception specification of a constructor for empty class type is non-throwing exception specification

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct Test{
  Test() = default;  // why the implicitly declared as non-throwing exception specification ?
};
```

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the form
>
> > X::X(const X&)
> > if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type M (or array thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type const M& or const volatile M&.119 Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form
> > X::X(X&)

According to [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), the implicitly declared copy constructor of class Test is `Test::Test(const X&)`, Because there's no any class type subobject.

So, similarly for exception specification,

According to the following rule:

> An implicitly-declared constructor for a class X, or a constructor without a noexcept-specifier that is defaulted on its first declaration, has a potentially-throwing exception specification if and only if any of the following constructs is potentially-throwing:
>
> > - a constructor selected by overload resolution in the implicit definition of the constructor for class X to initialize a potentially constructed subobject, or
> > - a subexpression of such an initialization, such as a default argument expression, or,
> > - for a default constructor, a default member initializer.

There's no any constructor  that selected for initializing subobject, and there's no any subexpression  of the initialization, and there's no any default member initializer.

The precondition is false, hence I consider the exception specification should be potentially-throwing, However why the defaulted constructor has non-throwing exception specification. I think it is unclear in the standard. If I misunderstand, please interpret this.

Comment: "*The precondition is false, hence I consider the exception specification should be potentially-throwing*" That's not what it says. It says that it will have a potentially-throwing specification only if one of those is true. Because none of those are true, it will not have a protentially throwing specification. Your logic makes no sense.

Comment: @NicolBolas Such as `if a constructor selected by overload resolution in the implicit definition of the constructor for class X to initialize a potentially constructed subobject has a  potentially-throwing exception specification`, however there's no constructor to be selected? So the proposition should be true.

Comment: That makes no sense. If there is no such constructor, then there can't be one selected, and the not-selected one cannot adhere to any property. That is, the set of constructors in that section is *zero*. And therefore *none* are "potentially-throwing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we have here is less a matter of formal logic and more a matter of what English words mean.

The text for the copy constructor form specifies "do the thing if each X has property Y". The text for the exception specifier says "do the thing if any X has property Y".

Now, if we look at the copy constructor case, what it's saying is equivalent to "do the thing if all X have property Y". Well, if the set X is empty, then "all of them" that exist do in fact have the property Y. So the condition is true.

By contrast, if "any X" is empty, then clearly there are not "any X" with that property since there are not "any X"es *at all*. So the condition is false.

If you contest this interpretation of the words "all" and "any", then look at how they get used elsewhere in programming. For example, the C++ standard library.

- `bitset::all` returns true on an empty set, while `bitset::any` returns false on an empty set.
- `std::all_of` returns true on an empty range; `std::any_of` returns false.

This is what the words *mean*.

Also, do note that the English examples in the Wikipedia article on Vacuous Truth all use the phrasing "all X are Y".

Comment: @NicoBolas If exists a constructor that has non-throwing exception specification, then the result is false, however you couldn't find a constructor that has non-throwing exception specification. Then it will be true, that is what [vacous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: @jackX: I don't know why you keep linking to that page as though it means something. The text is very clear as to what it's saying. Just *read it*.

Comment: @NicoBolas what's the difference between them , see [class.copy.ctor#7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#7), why here vacous truth applied to it if there's no any class type or only has scalar type. How to interpret the difference between them. Thanks

Comment: @NicoBolas However the sentence in class.copy.ctor#7 is `if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type M has the copy constructor of form Y`, think it in your way, that means it has to be some `subobject of a class type M` in order for `each` of them to have the property `Y`, Right?

Comment: @NicoBolas Rereading your answes carefully, you mean that the difference here is that  the condition is `any of the following`, the set is not empty due to there are three such constructs listed in the quote, so it's not the case of  vacous true, So, I shouldn't use that to analysis this quote, Right?

Comment: @jackX: What I'm saying is that `any X` is false if `X` is empty. That's what "any" means.

Comment: @jackX: Since you've changed the question to focus on that distinction, I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @NicoBolas  Please consider the following variant statement:  `any cell phone in the room is turned off`. if there's no cell phone in this room? what' the result? true or false?

Comment: @jackX: "*Please consider the following variant statement*" I'm not sure what the point of this question is. The meaning of the passes you quoted are clear. The way "any" is used in this context is clear and supported by multiple lines of evidence. The way "all" is used in other contexts is clear and supported by multiple lines of evidence. There's nothing left to discuss, so I don't know why you're insisting on continuing this conversation.

Comment: @NicoBolas what you want to say is that only the statement  is the form of `all X are Y`, it may be a case of vacuous truth?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218247/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-jack-x).

Comment: @NicoBolas Sorry, I just want to understand them. Now, I haven't understand the difference between them, if give the `bitset ` a actually empty set, whether `all` or `any`, they are all false. see https://godbolt.org/z/4K8Eon

Comment: The formally definition of `vacuous truth` is ∀∈:() (all elements of the set).

Comment: @jackX I can understand the confusion. It's possible to use "any" in place of "all" in general usage, thought this would be bad to use in technical language (e.g. "any human is a mammal" can be used to say "all humans are mammals", "any phone must be switched off" means "all phones must be switched off"). The form used here is "if any of these items satisfy property P", which always means "if at least one of these items satisfies P" or "if there exists an element of the set that satisfies P", i.e. ∃∈:().

Comment: @JosephIreland Yes,Yes, yes! You exactly understand what my confusion.  Here the phrase `any of` is equivalent `∃` (which is existential quantifier). Rather, the condition that conforms to `vacuous truth` is `for all` , `for every`, `for each`, namely `∀` (which is universal quantifier).